# Have a DIV not appear until it reaches a certain spot of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to have a div not appear until it reaches a point on a page.

My code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 50;        

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
      $('.divclass').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    }
    else {
      $('.divclass').hide();
    }
```

My issue:

The div is visible when page is reloaded. When I scroll down the div fades out and reloops animation. If I scroll up, the entire div disappears and I can't scroll down to that location anymore.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code, please?

Comment: is your division hidden initailly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide your div initially as ishwar rimal said. To do that you can add style to your div `display:none` or you can hide the div with jquery like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.divclass').hide()
})
```